# Should i say sallallahu alaihi wa sallam or alaihis salam within salat

Tags: salat, prophet-muhammad, dua, prophets

If Muslims hear or utter the name of any prophet (peace be upon them all) they say

> sallallahu alaihi wa sallam or alaihis salam ('peace be upon him')

For example, Muhammad (pbuh), Jesus (pbuh).

Are we allowed to say,

> Peace Be Upon Him

during Salah as the name of prophet Muhammad is mentioned?

Comment: Sunni view or Shia view? which madhab? which part of Salah?

Comment: something related [Question regarding Durood Shareef](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16805/question-regarding-durood-shareef)

Answer (score 1):

First lets define both of them.

> 1. ṣalla llāhu ʿalay-hi wa-alehe-wa-sallam

means you're praying to Allah saying "may Allah honour him and grant him peace"

> 2. ʿalayhi as-salām

means simply "**peace be upon him**".

There is verse in Qur'an which specifically says "peace be on the Messengers!" (Qur'an [37:181](http://quran.com/37/181)), from which it is generally implied that **whenever** we address the name of any prophet, we say, "peace be upon him" or in Arabic "ʿalayhi as-salām". (Read [more...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_be_upon_him_%28Islam%29))

But it is different when we address **Prophet Muhammad** where we're supposed to say (1) "**may Allah honour him and grant him peace**". This is usually what called [Durood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durood).

There are different variations of Durood. In salah, we recite the  famous "[Durood - E- Ibrahim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durood#Durood-i-Ibrahimi)"

One more place just before Durood - E _Ibrahim, we say "Shahada" as...

> 3. I testify that (there is) no god except God; One is He, no partner has He, and I testify that Muhammad is His servant and messenger

or in Arabic is "Ašhadu an lā ilāha illā-llāh waḥdahu lā šarīka lahu, wa ašhadu anna muḥammadan ʿabduhu wa rasūluhu."

So, right after hearing the name of Prophet Muhammmad, we don't say here "ṣalla llāhu ʿalay-hi wa-alehe-wa-sallam" (1) which is a smaller form of Durood, but we instead ask Allah in detail to bless Prophet Muhammad and his family by reading Durood - E - Ibrahim. which reads...

> 4. O Allah, let Your Peace come upon Muhammad and the family and followers of Muhammad, as you have brought peace to Ibrahim and his family. Truly, You are Praiseworthy and Glorious. Allah, bless Muhammad and the family and followers of Muhammad, as you have blessed Ibrahim and his family and followers. Truly, You are Praiseworthy and Glorious".

The above are the common places in Salah (prayer) where we encounter the saying of the name of Prophet Muhammad.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: "may Allah honour him and grant him peace" is not the complete translation of 1.

Comment: I think it is something like "Peace and **salah** of Allah be upon him" Read [More...](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16268/why-allah-send-darood-on-prophet-muhammadsaw) @BleedingFingers if it is anything else, plz feel free to let me know here.