# Why Allah send darood on Prophet Muhammad(saw)?

Tags: tafseer, prophet-muhammad, allah, arabic-translation

> ### إِنَّ اللَّهَ وَمَلَائِكَتَهُ يُصَلُّونَ عَلَى النَّبِيِّ ۚ يَا
> أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا صَلُّوا عَلَيْهِ وَسَلِّمُوا
> تَسْلِيمًا
>
> Allah and His Angels send blessings on the Prophet: O ye that believe!
> Send ye blessings on him and salute him with all respect.
> **Surah Ahzaab verse 56**

I have to think about this from a long time why Allah has to send his blessing toward Muhammad (saw). I mean Allah have All the power of the world and he accepts all blessing of mankind and every other living thing, then why He have to send his blessing?
I am sorry if I did not get the proper translation cause I don't know how to speak Arabic.

Comment: Allah himself sends blessing on the prophet is worth noting. I would like to know what type of blessings

Comment: It means darood!

Comment: So go would send darood on prophet Muhammad also? But He is giver, he is the one who accepts darood not the one who recite it. Imagine God saying this    اللَّهُمَّ صَلِّ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَعَلَى آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ كَمَا صَلَّيْتَ عَلَى إِبْرَاهِيمَ وَعَلَى آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ .إِنَّكَ حَمِيدٌ مَجِيدٌ

Comment: Yes I know but i have mentioned a Quranic verse which is saying that Allah send his blessing(darood) to the prophet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Blessing:** God's favor and protection (Oxford Standard Dictionary)

> It is He who confers **blessing upon you**, and His angels [ask Him to do so] that He may bring you out from darknesses into the light. And ever is He, to the believers, Merciful. (Qur'an 33:43)

The word Allah uses to describe his blessings upon us is 'yusalleeAAalaykum'=blessing upon you

> Indeed, Allah confers **blessing upon** the Prophet, and His angels [ask Him to do so]. O you who have believed, ask [ Allah to confer] blessing upon him and ask [ Allah to grant him] peace. (Qur'an 33:56)

The word Allah uses to describe his blessings upon the Prophet (peace be upon him) is 'yusalloonaAAala'=blessing upon

So, it is Allah who blesses us. BUT,

> Blessed is He in whose hand is dominion, and He is over all things competent (Qur'an 67:1)

The word Allah uses to describe himself is 'Tabaraka'= Blessed is He

So, is he blessing himself? Let's see further.

**bless:** to ask for God's help and protection for someone or something, or **to call or make someone or something Holy** (Cambridge Dictionary)

So, he is calling himself Holy here. In Arabic, some words don't have a very specific **meaning** but they **change according to the context**.

> And We have sent down **blessed** rain from the sky and made grow thereby gardens and grain from the harvest (Qur'an 50:9)

The word used here to describe rain is 'mubarakan'=blessed (as we say Eid Mubarak=Blessed Eid)

> Verily, man (disbeliever) was created very impatient; <sup>19</sup> ...Except those **devoted to Salat** (prayers) <sup>22</sup> (Qur'an 70:19 & 22)

The word used here is 'almusalleen'=devoted to Salat(who pray)

Not only these words, but other words e.g. 'Haq'=Truth or 'Haq'=Right(as in 'I don't have the right to speak') depends on the context and hence should not be confused.

SO, when we send **salah** to Allah, we ask him to bless us(have mercy us), when he sends **salah**, he is blessing us(showing mercy on us) and like wise on Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him)...

MAY THE CREATOR GUIDE US ALL.

Comment: I should not say, but this is the main reason why christians WORSHIP Jesus (pbuh) because he used the same words that is "Worship me" and "worship God" at different occasions. People instead of taking that as "Obey me" and "worship god" they literally took it as "Worship" in both cases. http://www.biblicalunitarian.com/videos/can-we-worship-jesus-christ

Comment: Can you quote the verse from the Bible where Jesus himself said that? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0wvuFp3M-o

Answer (score -1):

Allah Azjawajal himself sending Darood Sharif it means our realization that how importance of Rasoolallah Salallaho Alaih Wasallam. (Azmat e Rasool Salallaho Alaih wasallam and that’s called Maqam e Mustafa Salallaho Alaih Wasallam). As per Aquida e Ahlesunnah Allah is exempted Ibadaah but here it showing importance that Allah Azjawajal himself making Ibadah for his Habibullah Salallaho Alaih Wasallam. Allah gives hidaya to misguided people for right path.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please don't confound this site with a typical internet forum. I strongly suggest you to take the [tour], check our [help] and read [answer] to learn more how this site is supposed to work and how we expect our Q&A to be.