# Should we say the Prophet's full name during Durood Shareef?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, salawat

After reciting [Durood Shareef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salawat) (Allah Humma Salle Ala Muhammadin, and Allahumma Barik Ala), should we say our Prophet Muhammad Sallallahu Alaihi Wasallam's full name? Because, as we know, we should always pronounce His full name whenever we hear or say His name. In Durood Shareef, we say Allah Humma Salle Ala Muhammadin, and we actually say our Prophet's name. So, when we finish reciting Durood Shareef (not in between when reciting), should we say His full name too?

Comment: The full name of our prophet is **Durood** so you don't need to say full name of our prophet because you are already reciting **Durood**.

Comment: I thought the Durood Shareef is about praising our Prophet Muhammad SAW, not His name. Am I wrong?

Comment: I am not saying **Durood** is praising for our Prophet Muhammad's name I am saying the last part after Prophet Muhammad which is (SAW) is same as reciting **Durood** so if you are reciting Durood then you don't need to mention full name of Our Prophet (SAW).

Answer (score 2):

The full name of our beloved prophet(pbuh) is **Abū al-Qāsim Muḥammad ibn ʿAbd Allāh ibn ʿAbd al-Muṭṭalib ibn Hāshim** (Source [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad))

Did you ever hear that before? I just copy pasted it.

Major misconception is that "Sallallahu Alaihi Wasallam" is the extension of his name.

Sall + allahu +  Alaihi + Wasallam = May Blessings + of Allah + be on him + along with peace.(1)

Durood = Asking allah to send blessings upon Prophet(pbuh).

So, the above (1) Durood is the smallest of all the Durood. You don't have to say the full name of Prophet Muhammad(pbuh) but you should know this....

> Cursed be the person in whose presence my name is mentioned and he does not send Salawat(Durood) on me. Tirmidhi. (Source [Salawat Meaning](http://www.mahmoodjawaid.com/Salawat_-_Meaning___Implication.pdf))

Hence, it is highly advisable to say, Durood(the smallest Durood Sallallahu Alaihi Wasallam) after hearing his name.

To your question, you're already reading a big Durood([Durood-E-Ibrahim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durood#Durood-i-Ibrahimi)) salah(Namaz), then why the small [Durood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_be_upon_him_%28Islam%29)?

May the creator guide us all.